# How to filter out first few bad characters of Gerrit JSON api response

Tags: arrays, json, api, go, byte

In querying Gerrit, they intentionally put a `)]}'` at the beginning of their api response, see: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html. I am trying to remove it so the JSON is valid, but I'm unsure of the best way to do this in Go

this is my current program to query gerrit and pull out the changeID and the status from its json :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type gerritData struct {
    ChangeID string `json:"change_id"`
    Status   string `json:"status"`
}

func gerritQuery(gerrit string) (gerritData, error) {
    username := "redacted"
    password := "redacted"
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://gerrit.company.com/a/changes/?q="+gerrit, nil)
    req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

        // Trying to cut it out manually.
    respBody = respBody[:len(respBody)-4]

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var gerritResponse gerritData
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&gerritResponse); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return gerritResponse, nil
}

func main() {
    gerritFlag := flag.String("gerrit", "foo", "The Gerrit you want to query")
    flag.Parse()

    gerritResponse, _ := gerritQuery(*gerritFlag)

    fmt.Println(gerritResponse)
}
```

Go is still complaining with `panic: invalid character ')' looking for beginning of value`. I'm still new to the language so any advice would be great.

Comment: Although I'm not too familiar with JavaScript, it looks like you're cutting off some characters at the end, not at the beginning of the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question trims four bytes from the end of the response.

Trim the bytes from the beginning of the response:

```
 respBoby = respBody[4:]
```

Comment: ah, dumb mistake on my part thank you. now im getting a panic EOF but i can try to figure that out. thanks